# Как сделать такой url постов WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress, тема сделана мною, есть статьи разные Custom Post Type( Reviews, Services)

Как сделать, чтобы url был таким:

**У новостей**
*site.ru/blog/namePost*

**У отзывов**
*site.ru/reviews/namePost*

**У услуг**
*site.ru/services/namePost*

Если кратко, чтобы slug был до namePost.

Comment: А какой у них сей час url?

Comment: Так и будет при задании пермалинков /%postname%/ и дефолтной структуре в кастомных типах.